# Where is config information stored for LXDE panel's application launch bar?

Tags: panel, lxde

My system is Ubuntu with LXDE desktop installed.  I upgraded to 18.04 (did a Something Else install, formatted and installed /, didn't touch /home)

Now there are "broken icons" in the application launch bar of the LXDE panel that only show up when you go to the screen that lets you edit said application launch bar.

[image]

I was able to add applications and get my panel looking correct. The broken icons don't show up on the panel, fortunately.

I tracked down the config file for the panel to `/home/[user]/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel`.  Here is a code snippet for the `remmina` entries.

> ```
> Button {
>   id=org.remmina.Remmina.desktop
> }
> Button {
>   id=/usr/share/applications/remmina.desktop
> }
> ```

I thought I could remove the code for the 2nd button (the broken one) and be done.  I edited the file and saved it.  No change though, and when I re-opened the file, the lines I removed are back.

So this file is being built based on data entries stored somewhere else.  That makes sense.

*But where can I find these other entries, so I can delete the bad ones?*